# Using Autohotkey on non active window

Tags: autohotkey

I have a program that starts up with a splash screen and it is common to have multiple copies of the program opened at same time.  I'm trying to get a script to start the program and autologin (as a start) from the #z sequence.  However, the program can start in the background (ie out of focus) and I'm having issues trying to send the login keys correctly.

My script is as follows:

```
Run, "C:\Users\myusername\wIntegrate\Session\MANFACT.WIC",,,PID
WinWait, ahk_pid %PID%,,,About
WinGetTitle, ID, ahk_pid %PID%
ControlSend, ,myusername{Enter},%ID%
ControlSend, ,mypassword{Enter},ahk_id %ID%
```

Can someone give me some pointers on how to do this?

Shawn Way

Comment: *"I'm having issues trying to send the login keys correctly."* What exactly is happening? Is it not working at all or just inconsistent?

Comment: It is starting the program but it is not sending the username or password to the background application.

Comment: For visitor reference, here's the discussion on AHK forums: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=70461&p=304275

Comment: Can you share the program on Dropbox or something else so we can test it?
And by "the program can start in the background (ie out of focus)" do you mean you don't want to WinActivate the program?